# Highest damage weapon?

Tags: terraria

How much damage does the best weapon in Terraria do?

Answer (score 12):

[Coin Gun](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Coin_Gun) is the most powerful weapon, if platinum coins are used as ammo, which can deal 200 damage and has an *insanely fast* rate of fire.

If you want to see each weapon sorted for its *Damage* or *Damage-per-second*, see [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/List_of_weapons).

Answer (score 7):

As of [1.4](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/1.4.0.1), the strongest single-target weapon is the [Zenith](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Zenith), which can deal around 70k DPS at its maximum. It averages roughly 30k DPS in standard gameplay, and can also hit multiple targets, making it the best all-around weapon in the game.

This surpasses the [Coin Gun's](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Coin_Gun) 1735 DPS, although the Coin Gun remains the best ranged option. You may want to use the [S.D.M.G](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/S.D.M.G.) if money is a concern.

The best magic weapon remains the [Last Prism](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Last_Prism) (although it has an ungodly mana cost), but the best summoner weapon is the [Terraprisma](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraprisma). However, the [Stardust Dragon Staff](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stardust_Dragon_Staff) and [Stardust Cell Staff](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stardust_Cell_Staff) still serve as viable weapons for lategame with specific builds.. The [Kaleidoscope](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Kaleidoscope) serves as the best Whip option (whips are summoner weapons also added in 1.4), though if you're using the Stardust Dragon Staff, the [Firecracker](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Firecracker) may be preferable as it increases the dragon's damage more than the Kaleidoscope does.

Answer (score 1):

The best melee weapon in the game is the Terrarian. While Coin Gun and Meowmere seem better, the Coin Gun requires a lot of money if you want high dps, and the Meowmere can deal mostly 1000 damage with a projectile, while the Terrarian deals 190 dmg and throws projectiles with the same damage, AND if combined with the Yoyo Bag, it's dps get's to 5000 easily, and that with a single enemy.

In conclusion, the Terrarian is the best melee weapon, the best ranged weapon is the S.D.M.G., the strongest magic weapon is the Last Prism, the strongest summoning weapon is the Stardust Dragon Staff, and the strongest sentry is the Rainbow Crystal Staff(excluding the Tavernkeep's sentries, which the best is Ballista staff).

Answer (score 0):

The best melee weapon is the Meowmere, as it does 200 damage. The internet has a bunch of different items that say are the best but I know that is best for swords. :D

Answer (score 0):

The best on IOS is the possessed hatchet .It's a must have drops of the GOLEM

Answer (score -2):

The coin gun is the most powerful ranged weapon, and
the terrablade is the most powerful sword in the game
Unless you count the horsemans blade which in total does more damage than terrablade because of its pumpkins that it spawns with the right setup. (never use in duke fishron fight cause you need vampire knives and terrablade)

Answer (score -2):

There is no best weapon because someone could ask meaning magicaly or attack wise. So you would want to go in between with the True Excalibur or The Legendary Picksaw.

Answer (score -3):

The Terra Blade has the best sword damage. The best summoner is the Frost Hydra. The best magic is the anchor spell. Rainbow Gun/Rod, Paladin Hammer and The Possessed Hatchet are the best boomerangs. The best bow is the Vulcan Repeater. The best armor is full turtle accessories (in my opinion), Flame Gauntlet, hoverboard, ankh, shield, lightning boots and Master Ninja gear. The best gun is Clockwork Rifle and Mega Shark with Chlorophyte bullets.

Answer (score -5):

sniper rifle. it does a crit. of over 620 dps. i rest my case. it just has a slow speed