# What are these weird 1 wide vertical tunnels?

Tags: terraria

I found these 1-block-wide tunnels that went straight down while exploring. I didn't get to the bottom of them, as you can see by my short tunnel beside the one on the left.

Since I couldn't get to them, I decided to pull up Terramap and take a quick look, and found it. However, there's another one right by it, so now I know it isn't just some weird occurrence. I went to the gamepedia, and I haven't found anything on it. What is it?

[image: image of structure]

Answer (score 10):

These are [enchanted sword shrines](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Enchanted_Sword_Shrine).

> A Shrine is marked by a long, narrow vertical shaft that may reach the surface, and features a small hill with Flower Walls and pools of water on either side. The breakable sword sprite rests atop the hill.

[image: enchanted sword shrine]

If you are lucky (33% chance), you can find an [Enchanted Sword](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Enchanted_Sword_%28item%29) or [Arkhalis](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Arkhalis) in there, which are pretty nice if you get them early in the game.

Comment: The Arkhalis can be useful even into the beginning of hardmode - in swarms of enemies it can do 600+ DPS. Note that there is only a 1/10 chance of getting it from a real sword sprite (which has a 1/3 chance of spawning)

Comment: The Enchanted Sword is also required when you want to craft the [most powerful melee weapon as of 1.4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377846/26705), the [Zenith](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Zenith)